# prevent facebook from uploading images with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to build a chrome extension which processes images in the background, before they are uploaded to facebook, to protect privacy of the users.
My problem is that i can't prevent facebook from uploading the images directly after chosen by the user. To accomplish this i tried inject some JavaScript which registers an onChange Listener:

```
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('_n _5f0v');
for(i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
    //inputElements[i].addEventListener('change', handleImages, true);
    inputElements[i].onchange = handleImages;
}

function handleImages(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Image upload');
    return false;
}
```

However this does not work, because the image is uploaded anyway. The alert is fired correctly, but preventDefault seems not to work here, because the facebook upload script is handled somewhere else. 
Any clue on how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events handling isn't working this way.

To unregister previously registered function you have to pass this function as a (second) parameter. Since you can't (because content scripts does not have access to hosting page scripts) you can't also remove listener for form submission. 
You can't depend on preventDefault either because you can't be sure which event will be fired first.

I think you can try to replace the form responsible for files upload but I'm not sure if it is possible in case of Facebook. If you can, you can do whatever you want.